# Spacing between page number and chapter heading

Tags: sectioning, titles, page-numbering, page

I am writing a chapter of my thesis in Latex, the page numbers are on top left corner which are adjusted with the chapter heading as shown in the picture :

[image]

While 2 is the page number and I need a space between 2 and Chapter 1. My code is just

```
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt, titlepage]{book} 
\chapter{Guided Wave Based Structural Health Monitoring}
\textbf{My name}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
```

when I give the chapter name shorter it works fine but when I write the complete name/title of the chapter, it makes this problem. 
I am new to Latex, please help me with this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Please rewrite your code as `\documentclass[b5paper, 11pt, titlepage]{book}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter Title}
\textbf{My name}
\end{document}` It seems to print the page numbers fine when I compiled.

Comment: @hesham I do not know why it does not have any space in my latex/system.

Comment: There are many latex book templates you can start with, e.g., https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/basic-book-template-by-amber-jain/pdhjnypqfzsv. Another source of a variety of templates can also be found here https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/tagged/book. Good luck!

Comment: @hesham Thanks.

Comment: "I do not know why it does not have any space in my latex/system." Your posted code has extra punctuation here `\documentclass[b5paper,11pt, titlepage]{book},` (the end comma), and its order is wrong. Try the code I posted in the first comment and start modifying it from there.

Comment: @hesham Thanks, no there is no ',' in my Latex command, anyway, I edited the complete post if you can answer. Thanks.

Comment: You still need to add `\begin{document}` ... `\end{document}`

Comment: @hesham That have already been added.

Comment: Additionally the width of the page that you selected by `b5paper` seems insufficient for your chapter long title, this is why the title is coming very close to the page number.

Comment: @hesham It works but the b5paper is university/institute requirement, I cannot change the width/size of the page.

Comment: @hesham Yes, Thanks. I can submit like this at the moment but actually I was looking for reducing the font size of the title. I think that will work fine with my case.

Comment: You can ask this in another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem rises from the width of the page that you selected `b5paper` being of insufficient width for your chapter long title which causes the title to become very close to the page number in the header.

You can solve this problem by adding `\chaptermark{short version of the chapter title}` after the chapter command. So the complete code can be:

```
\documentclass[b5paper, 11pt, titlepage]{book}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Guided Wave Based Guided Wave Based Structural Health Monitoring}
\chaptermark{Guided Wave Based ...} % Short version of your chapter title that will appear in the header only.
\newpage
\textbf{My name}
\end{document}
```

And the ouptut

[image]